# Tornado WebSocket Server without proxy

Tags: nginx, websocket, tornado

I have a tornado websocket server that works fine on my local machine. but when I deploy it to a web server and run it with supervisord I cant connect with javascript websockets.
I have tried to open the port in firewall but doesnt work.
I also tried to use a proxy with nginx (and the tcp module)

```
tcp {
    upstream websockets {
        server abc.de.efg.hij:23581;
        check interval=3000 rise=2 fall=5 timeout=1000;
    }

    server {
        listen abc.de.efg.hij:45645;
        server_name _;

        tcp_nodelay on;
        proxy_pass websockets;
    }
}
```

but also doesnt work.
whats wrong here?

Comment: Try to use `haproxy`.

Comment: You can now use Nginx as a reverse proxy for websockets. See [proxying-websockets-with-nginx](https://chrislea.com/2013/02/23/proxying-websockets-with-nginx/) for a how-to.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an extra 'location' section for the websocket to make sure the upgrade headers are passed correctly:

```
location /YOUR_SOCKET_ENDPOINT/ {
    proxy_pass http://backend;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
}
```

Docs are here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/websocket.html